# SQL Query which helps me to get me no of "y"s in a column

Tags: php, mysql

i want show how many "y"s are there in a date

i wonder whether is there any thing like that :(

i want to display the numner of "Y"s in 2013.01.01 column

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");
mysql_select_db("", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date = '2013.01.01'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows";
?>
```

**My TABLE (Attendance)**

```
date        pt17   pt18    pt19    pt20     pt21     pt22     pt23    pt24

2013.01.01    y     n        y       n         y               y        n
2013.01.02    n     n        y                 y      y        y        n
2013.01.03    n     y        n       y         n      y        n        n
  ......
```

DESIRE OUTPUT:

```
no. of presents on 2013.01.01 are 4
```

Comment: You could try COUNT(YEAR(date))

Comment: Can you show how would your desired output be as you have done for you table ?

Comment: @user2457175 and you want to format that on your PHP and not on your MySQL query is that correct ?

Comment: First normalize your data. A sql table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Comment: @Prix is that possible to do like that...

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than linear search. PHP may have some function to count occurrence of a string in an array but it should also be of linear complexity.

Comment: @user2457175 on PHP its rather easy but on MySQL query would be slight complicated.

Comment: @Prix no problem. i just need to result :( if possible can you please answer this question with the possible way to get my desire result. PHP is ok..

Comment: Instead of this, have one column named `date`, one named `pt_number` and one named `value` (tinyint - either 0 or 1). This way it'd be **way** easier, and you'd normalize the data instead of this.

Comment: @user2457175 have posted my answer it should work for as many columns as you have excluding the date one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base sql query for that is

```sql
SELECT COALESCE((pt17 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt18 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt19 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt20 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt21 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt22 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt23 = 'y'), 0)
      +COALESCE((pt24 = 'y'), 0) num
  FROM attendance
 WHERE date = '2013.01.01'
```

Output:

```
| NUM |
-------
|   4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f71835/7)** demo

---

Your php part, assuming that you still use `mysql_` extension might look like

```php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$date = '2013.01.01';

$sql = "SELECT COALESCE((pt17 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt18 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt19 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt20 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt21 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt22 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt23 = 'y'), 0)
              +COALESCE((pt24 = 'y'), 0) num
          FROM attendance
         WHERE date = '$date'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $num_of_present = $row['num'];  
}
echo "no. of presents on 2013.01.01 are $num_of_present";
```

Comment: how to show this result in front end. will this work? `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows";`

Comment: thanks a ton :) it worked great! but the problem is it is displaying the result as `string(1) "2" ` 2 is the answer. how can i remove that `string(1)` how can i change the display as `no of presents : 5`

Comment: @user2457175 You're welcome :) See updated answer. You can change last line with `echo` to whatever you like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT concat("no. of presents on ",date," are", 
if(pt17='y',1,0)+
if(pt18='y',1,0)+
if(pt19='y',1,0)+
if(pt20='y',1,0)+ 
if(pt21='y',1,0)+ 
if(pt22='y',1,0)+ 
if(pt23='y',1,0)+
if(pt24='y',1,0) )
 FROM attendance WHERE date = '2013.01.01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "vishnu65_ven", "vishnu65_ven");
mysql_select_db("vishnu65_ven", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE date = '2013.01.01'", $link);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_rows($result)){
    $num_of_y = 0;
    foreach($rows as $row){
         if($row == 'y')
            $num_of_y++;
    }
    echo 'Number of y = '.$num_of_y;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plain answers are already given by peterm and chetan. So I'll just give an alternative solution. I'm not sure what the context is of the ptXX-columns, but they seem to be generic. If so it could be better to restructure your table to the following.

```
Attendance
DATE | PT-ID | status(y/n/_)
```

*(if necessary add a table which defines the PT-ID's)*
Using this table-structure you can easily request the attendance of at a specific date, without the need of using the advanced (and in my opinion hardcoded) queries given here.